# Using IE11 a very basic javascript alert() does not pop up a window. Only beeps

Tags: javascript, popup, alert, internet-explorer-11

Very odd problem.  Using IE11 a very basic javascript alert() does not pop up a window.  I have reset my settings and disabled the popup blocker, but still getting the same behavior.  Here is the code, I tested it on the following page:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me, looked in the F12 error console?

Comment: May be check if Javascript is enabled?

Comment: Yes, I viewed the F12 console.  Nothing shows up when I click the button.  However I'm getting a series of errors and warnings in the console window:SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://ie.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/8C425DF4-1F7E-0C45-B396-38D158F34E0B/CD385799-F32A-0C42-9234-31C91EC9B404/from required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
File: container.html

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
File: cTrvNaRi.html, Line: 1, Column: 1

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
File: container.html, Line: 1, Column: 1

Comment: try to place your js function in head

Comment: Moving function to the <head> did not fix.

Comment: JS is enabled too ("Active Scripting")

Comment: The error is unrelated to your code, A/V toolbar perhaps?

Comment: UPDATE:  Still not working.  I uninstalled IE11, then installed IE10.  I tested another script and got same behavior:  Just a beep, no activity, nothing in the F12 Console, just beep beep beep.  Here is the one line code I tested: <a href="JavaScript:alert('hello');">CLICK ME</a>.  Worked fine in Chrome and FF but not IE.  I also saw someone suggesting IE not the problem but Windows 7, either registry corruption or AV like Mcafee

Comment: Update.  Looks like Kaspersky AV caused the problem due to Javascript injection.  The same thing was happening on a different laptop and I uninstalled Kasperkly.  Voila!  The problem went away.  Now to find an alternate AV program...

Comment: I'm having the same issues... the alert box did not show. I have McAfee, but its disabled. Can't uninstall due to it being a client's laptop. Seeking a work around. Will publish my findings.

Comment: UPDATE: Completely my fault. I just discovered that text() on a textarea to retrieve the data with JQuery works with IE but not with Chrome or FF which requires val()... never saw this one before thus validation is not failing.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with you button settings.

these 2 buttons will call 2 javascripts without any problem

1. HTML button-classic asp

`<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" runat="server">Try it</button>`

2. web control button

`<asp:Button ID="btnCall" runat="server" style="margin-top: 1px" Text="Exit App." OnClientClick="play()" />`

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you